# How to hide the SharePoint document libraries from site contents?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

One of the Requirements I am working for, I am getting a list of all the Document libraries present in the SharePoint site using JSOM. Now I have to hide these document libraries from all the users, Just FYI, this is not permissions based. The behavior will be uniform across all users.

I am using below code to get the list of all the libraries.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var currentcontext = null;
    var currentweb = null;
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetLibrariesOnly, "sp.js");

    //to get the list of document libraries.
    function GetLibrariesOnly()
    {
    currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
    this.listCollection = currentweb.get_lists();
    listCollection.set_hidden(true);
    currentcontext.load(listCollection);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure));
    }
    function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {
    var listEnumerator = this.listCollection.getEnumerator();
       var allLibs ="";
       while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) 
       {
                var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
                if(list.get_baseTemplate() == '101')
                {
                 allLibs+= list.get_title() + '\n';                
                }
       }
        alert("All Libraries:" + '\n' + allLibs);
     }
    function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) {
    alert("Error in Getting Libraries");
    }
```

What should I add/change to hide the libraries except the Documents and Site Assets library that appear in the Alert.

I would want to hide all the libraries except site assets and default documents library. Please see below screenshot. I am working with SharePoint online/Office 365. Thanks in advance.

[image: Alert Console in Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

following css will hide all the tiles site contents:

```
<style>
.ms-vl-apptile.ms-vl-apptilehover {display :none;}
</style>
```

following javascript will help to display your required tiles and this will work for all tiles:

```
<script>
$('a[title="Documents"]').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').css("display","inline-block");
$('a[title="Site Assets"]').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').css("display","inline-block");
$('a[title="Style Library"]').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').css("display","inline-block");
</script>
```

Note: you have to add this **javascript** and **css** reference or js and css code themselves in your **MasterPage**. **Don't forget to include jquery references.**

Comment: just wanted to confirm when you say tiles, do you mean document libraries? right

Comment: Not just document libraries but also "Site Pages", "Style Library" , "Site Assets", "Documents" etc. So basically hiding all tiles using css and displaying only tiles those are needed using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Gopal. Can I reverse the approach? Like initially your code will hide everything when display set to none. Can I set the display to inline-block initially so everything is visible upfront and then in code under script tag, I can set the display to none to hide selected libraries, does that work?

Comment: Yeah, Surely That will work But that will blink the document libraries when the page is loading and then disappeared. Please Don't forget to mark as answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Also, one more thing I wanted to ask is, even though the tiles will get hidden, if a user knows the url, it's still accessible. Do you if we can make them not access the library when its hidden and when its not then we should allow accessing the users though url as well.

Comment: No, Actually It's not possible even not programmatically. By the way the end uses might not be aware of this URLs. You can make them inaccessible using permissions.

Comment: Thanks gopal. The code u suggested, I am going to put it into my JS function, I have included the jquery reference and style tag in the same js file. Is this okay?

Comment: Devang , you can not add style tag in J's file , Can you ? it's CSS.

Comment: Gopal I can not put this into Master page as the functionality is driven from a collaboration list so I have to hide the document libraries using JS. Also the custom master page I have is applied to each site so I can't do that. Hiding of document libraries would only work for certain sites which is driven from a collaboration  list.

Comment: Then go for only J's files. avoid css files.  